# Calling Azure function from a javascript to get SAS Token can breach security?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, blob, azure-functions

I have a Azure function similar to Node.js Azure Function for generating SAS tokens to get SAS Token.

Now i have a application where i need to show Azure Blob document using SAS Token in a iframe. Now i want to use the azure function to get the SAS Token in a javascript function as i have to show in the document in  pop screen in iframe, my question is as per below:

1. How to call the azure function form my javascript. Even if i call the azure function using node.js i have to pass the function app url and function/admin key which i guess is a security breach as these can be sniffed from browser . Can anybody suggest how to acheive the requirement keeoing the security intact.

Comment: if you're using azure ad authentication to your fucntion app, it should be ok. Otherwise if your nodejs app call the function app (server to server) it is ok. Your nodejs app is a server side app or you're talking about about a client side app (SPA)  which is not a nodejs app ?

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your inout,The node.js is clinet side app. Any other suggestion how to use in client sode?

Comment: do your users authenticate to your app ? are you already using azure active directory ? what framework are you using for the front end: react, vue, angular something else ?btw a web client side app is not a nodejs app

Comment: No not authenticated yet. I am using simple Javascript Ajax call to get SAS token from Azure function app

Comment: when you said `not yet`, do you plan to add azure ad auth and requires user auth ?

Comment: Yes, I have but i have to give a second thought beacuse there are 10k users in our Azure AD and i do not to give rights to everyoe to generate SAS token.

Comment: i guess you can use a security group and check the claims ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set IP restriction for your Azure function in "Platform features" =>"General Settings" => "All settings" => "Networking" => "IP Restrictions" to ensure only your application IP will be able to access it.